# Method "session:peer:didChangeState"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

I read that article : " http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1 "

I want to integrate in my application Bluetooth. I had a problem. I want to connect 2 devices and i want to know if the function "session:peer:didChangeState" is called on the both device. In my opinion i think it is called on the both devices.

I want to know if the method session:peer:didChangeState is called on the both devices .

I want to send via bluetooth a structure: 
My structure is following :

```
typedef struct Package
{
    tip_Comunicare_Enum type;
    union mesaj_Comunicare
    {
        Msg_Cerere_Struct msg_Cerere;
        Msg_Raspuns_Struct msg_Raspuns;
        Msg_Initializare msg_Initializare;
    }mesaj_Comunicare;
}
Package ;
```

My serializer looks like that :

```
-(void) SendData:(Package *) pachet
{
NSLog(@"Send DATA pachet");

printf("%d\n",sizeof(*pachet));

NSData * myData = [[NSData dataWithBytes:pachet 
                                  length:sizeof(*pachet)] autorelease]; 
[self mySendDataToPeers:myData];
}
```

If i use like that it is doesn't work and i give SIGKILL or something like that.

Thant for the time spent with me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData * myData = [[NSData dataWithBytes:pachet 
                                  length:sizeof(*pachet)] autorelease];
```

myData is already autoreleased. You have to write:

```
NSData * myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:pachet 
                                  length:sizeof(*pachet)];
```

Remember: autorelease message is sent as many times as it is called.

Comment: I still have the following error: wait_fences: failed to receive reply : 1000403

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003