# iPhone Objective C - wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alert, reply

i have this strange error : wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 in this code :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        [self showActivityViewer];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideActivityViewer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdatePoi];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdateItinerari];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdateEventi];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdateArtisti];
        NSLog(@"AGGIORNA");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NON AGGIORNARE");
        return;
    }
}
```

Why?? Where could be the possibile error or problem??

Comment: are you running any thread or are you calling thread from other threads ?

Comment: This alert appear at the applicationDidFinishLaunching method. I don't think other threads is called.

Comment: FYI: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003 gives some more in-depth information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens if you try to push/present another view controller **before the alert view is actually dismissed**. This happened when I ran one of my apps in iOS 4. I don't know the exact reason for this problem, but you can resolve this by moving all the code from *clickedButtonAtIndex:* method to  **didDismissWithButtonIndex:** method.