# Debugging wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: iphone, debugging

Can someone tell me how I can debugg this error "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003" I am not quite sure where in the code it gets called as it happens during startup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where it happens.. I don't have any viewWillAppear..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check these out:

["wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003)

Hope this helps you.

Please feel free to let me know, if you need more help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a universal way to break on that message, however, based on a comment in the apple dev forums, I was able to figure out a cause I haven't seen turn up on stackoverflow or in google.

My app has the status bar initially hidden so it isn't there when the default.png is displayed. In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: I was calling [application setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:YES]. Commenting out that call removed the message. It didn't matter if the animation flag was NO. Wrapping this cal in a dispatch_async also removed the message.

Answer (score 1):

I used to get the same debug message and could not find any sort of answer, on a off chance I set the Split Keyboard setting to OFF. Settings - General-Keyboard-Split Keyboard - OFF. So far it has worked for me. Co-incidence... IDK.