# TTURLRequestModel fails to call requestDidFinishLoad when app enters foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

My App makes a request through a TTURLRequestModel for a weekly set of images. When app launches for the first time, this request goes through successfully and gets a response back successfully.

When app is closed and relaunched, applicationDidBecomeActive method posts a notification to update the weekly list and makes a request through that same TTURLRequestModel. Only this time, you can see the the request is sent successfully but requestDidFinishLoad never gets called. I have requestDidFailLoadWithError implemented, and tested that the request gets started.

In the view controller, the init method allocates the model and assigns delegates.

```
photoListData = [[PhotoListDataModel alloc] init];
[[photoListData delegates] addObject:self];
```

The method that listens for the notification makes the request:

```
[photoListData cancel];
[photoListData load:TTURLRequestCachePolicyNoCache more:NO];
```

Any insight on what may be causing this behavior will be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: After some more debugging, i managed to produce [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003) .

I Realized that I forgot to call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` on my viewcontroller. Not entirely, sure if and how this might have fixed this issue, but I am getting a response back now for my load request. Any insight on this mystery will still be appreciated though!