# 'wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003' on loading UIAlertView (iOS)

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm getting the 'wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003' when I call a UIAlertView. It's called when the app first opens. It doesn't crash the app or seem to effect the functionality of it at all but I want to clean up my app completely. It's a tab bar app and I've entered the code in the viewDidLoad section of the View Controller that's first loading in the app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Welcome!" message:@"Thanks for downloading our new app! \n \n Take a look around and if you have any questions, don't hesitate to contact us." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

I have seen other answers on the site to this error but they seem to deal with UITextFields and I'm not sure how they apply to my situation exactly. I apologize if I'm missing something simple, but I'm learning hands-on and can't seem to figure this one out. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should show it in `-(void)viewDidAppear` method. When view just loaded it is not on screen.

Comment: @Roman: Post your comment as an answer so that Mxmasta can accept it :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, dooooo it. :)

Comment: FYI: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003 gives some more in-depth information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should show it in `-(void)viewDidAppear` method. When view just loaded it is not on screen.