# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 (only on iPad)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, error-handling

I know there are a lot of threads abou this. The crazy thing about my situation is that I've tested a 3GS, a 4S and an iPad1, and it consistently happens only on the iPad1. It happens at launch. The app continues to run. However, the first time I open an [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), when I go to dismiss it, it doesn't dismiss, and therefore my app becomes unresponsive at that point.

Please let me know what could causing this, and why it only happens on the iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have had this problem, it is because you are displaying a view (like a `UIAlertView`) or updating the view before it has finished loading properly. Move the call to MBProgressHUD out of your `viewDidLoad` or out of your Application Delegate to stop this message.

I usually move my `UIAlertView` calls into the `viewWillAppear` method.

Here is a similar question: ['wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003' on loading UIAlertView (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337183/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003-on-loading-uialertview-ios)

This message can also appear when you try updating the UI from a background thread. [More Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241894/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003-error-uialert-without-uitextfie?rq=1)

Comment: I added a 1 second delay before displaying the HUD. Seems to fix it. Not sure why they can't give us a better error message though.