# Not release NSMutableString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5

I started developing a project in ios-5, I have created database in my application.
Here I create bdgDBArr in appDelegate that contains values like 93,55,68,95,45...
I want to create string like badge_id= @"93,55,68,95,45"
here appDelegate.sb is `NSString` type and sb1 is `NSMutableString` type

This is my code

```
NSMutableString *sb1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

if (![appDelegate.bdgDBArr count]==0) {
    for (int i=0; i < [appDelegate.bdgDBArr count]; i++)  { 
        if (!i==0) {
             [sb1 appendString:@","];
        }
        [sb1 appendString:[[appDelegate.bdgDBArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"key1"]];
    }
}
else {
    [sb1 appendString:@""];
}

appDelegate.sb = sb1;
NSLog(@"appDelegate.sb  showSB===%@",appDelegate.sb);
[sb1 release];  //error wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
sb1 = nil;
```

This code is working perfectly and get the output 93,55,68,45
but at the same time I got this error in NSLog

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have ARC turned on, in that case you don't need to release the object.

Comment: @rckoenes Looks like runtime exception not a compilation error. Whereas ARC is done at compile time.

Comment: possible duplicate : [http://stackoverflow.com/q/1371346/971401](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1371346/971401).

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with your problem but you can — and should — reduce your code down to a one-liner: `appDelegate.sb = [appDelegate.bdgDBArr componentsJoinedByString:@","];` which is much more expressive and does the right thing.

And while we're there:
Objective-C makes it rather easy to write code that can be read like prose. Don't break that by using member/variable names like `sb` or `bdgDBArr`.

Oh and there is an operator to test for inequality: `!=` use that instead of negating the result of an equality test. Your future self and every other person looking at your code will be thankful.

Comment: appDelegate.sb = [[appDelegate.bdgDBArr valueForKey:@"key1"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];

Answer (score 0):

just to try: use autorelease instead of release. does it change something?

is your property appDelegate.sb used in app delegate with a @syntetise setter/getter, or did you used your own code for the setter? in this case post your code, please.