# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 when Load a UIWebview in tabbar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

My application start with navigation Controller based, then change to Tabbar base after user login. If the second tab is selected, then it will presentModalViewController. In this viewController, I load a webview as normal I do. But the problem is for first time I do presentModalViewController, then I get the warning message above and it likes un-responded for few seconds before presentModalViewController (webpage is still loaded fully-no crashed). After the first time, it's normal (no warning message-very smooth).

I tried to take out the webview, I do presentModalViewController with a image instead. It's okay(no warning message). However, If i drag Uiwebview in IB into my viewcontroller only without any connecting with IBoutlets. I still get that warning message.

I did a lot of researches like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003), I tried to load the Url request in both ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear, but it didn't help

My question is how can I pass by the warning? and is it okay to ignore this warning since this is my first time getting this warning?

Please help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ignore the warning. It will not cause any crashes
.

Answer (score 0):

Try -viewDidAppear:

This seems to happen when multiple animations conflict.