# crash with AVCapture based viewController

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cadisplaylink, wait-fences

I m working on an app which use OpenGL VideoCapture inside a UIViewController

on the first init of this controller I get this message in the console:

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

the message is displayed right after viewController init

After that, if I switch to another controller and start this controller again , a crash occurs after 2/4 launch of the ViewController with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

the asm output doesnt help that much

```
0x32f56a34:  bne    0x32f56ad4               ; memmove$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 276
0x32f56a38:  subs   r2, r2, #60
0x32f56a3c:  blo    0x32f56a84               ; memmove$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 196
0x32f56a40:  tst    r0, #28
0x32f56a44:  beq    0x32f56a5c               ; memmove$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 156
0x32f56a48:  ldr    r3, [r1], #4
0x32f56a4c:  subs   r2, r2, #4
0x32f56a50:  str    r3, [r0], #4
0x32f56a54:  bhs    0x32f56a40               ; memmove$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 128
0x32f56a58:  b      0x32f56a84               ; memmove$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 196
0x32f56a5c:  push   {r5, r6, r8, r10}
0x32f56a60:  ldm    r1!, {r3, r4, r5, r6, r8, r9, r10, r12}
0x32f56a64:  subs   r2, r2, #64
```

Some relealant part of the source code here :

```
- (id)init
{

    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {

        ADLog(@"AR_ogl_ViewController init");

        animating = FALSE;

        EAGLContext *aContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

        if (!aContext)
        {
            aContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
        }

        if (!aContext)
        {
            ADLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
        }
        else if (![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:aContext])
        {   
            ADLog(@"Failed to set ES context current");
        }

        self.context = aContext;

        ADSafeRelease(aContext);


        [(AR_EAGLView *)self.view setContext:context];
        [(AR_EAGLView *)self.view setFramebuffer];

        [self createVBO];

        if ([context API] == kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2)
            [self loadShaders];

        animating               = FALSE;
        displayLinkSupported    = FALSE;
        animationFrameInterval  = 1;
        displayLink             = nil;
        animationTimer          = nil;

        // Use of CADisplayLink requires iOS version 3.1 or greater.
        // The NSTimer object is used as fallback when it isn't available.
        /*  NSString *reqSysVer = @"3.1";

        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

        if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)*/

        displayLinkSupported = TRUE;

        // start capture
        [self setupCaptureSession];

        // initialize
        frameData = 0;
        pTexData = (GLuint*)malloc(TEX_SIZE*TEX_SIZE*sizeof(GLuint));

        incrementNeedsVideoFrame();

        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
        float z = 1.0f;
        float angle = 90.0 * PI_OVER_180;

        afIdentity[0]  = 1+(1-cos(angle))*(x*x-1);
        afIdentity[1]  = -z*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*y;
        afIdentity[2]  = y*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*z;
        afIdentity[3]  = 0;
        afIdentity[4]  = z*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*y;
        afIdentity[5]  = 1+(1-cos(angle))*(y*y-1);
        afIdentity[6]  = -x*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*y*z;
        afIdentity[7]  = 0;
        afIdentity[8]  = -y*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*z;
        afIdentity[9]  = x*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*y*z;
        afIdentity[10] = 1+(1-cos(angle))*(z*z-1);
        afIdentity[11] = 0;
        afIdentity[12] = 0;
        afIdentity[13] = 0;
        afIdentity[14] = 0;
        afIdentity[15] = 1;

        y = 1.0f;
        z = 0.0f;
        angle = 180.0 * PI_OVER_180;

        afIdentity2[0]  = 1+(1-cos(angle))*(x*x-1);
        afIdentity2[1]  = -z*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*y;
        afIdentity2[2]  = y*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*z;
        afIdentity2[3]  = 0;
        afIdentity2[4]  = z*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*y;
        afIdentity2[5]  = 1+(1-cos(angle))*(y*y-1);
        afIdentity2[6]  = -x*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*y*z;
        afIdentity2[7]  = 0;
        afIdentity2[8]  = -y*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*x*z;
        afIdentity2[9]  = x*sin(angle)+(1-cos(angle))*y*z;
        afIdentity2[10] = 1+(1-cos(angle))*(z*z-1);
        afIdentity2[11] = 0;
        afIdentity2[12] = 0;
        afIdentity2[13] = 0;
        afIdentity2[14] = 0;
        afIdentity2[15] = 1;

    }

    ADLog(@"AR_ogl_ViewController init end");


    return self;

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    ADLog(@"dealloc");
    ADSafeRelease(session);

    //ADSafeRelease(input);
    //ADSafeRelease(output);

    if (program)
    {
        glDeleteProgram(program);
        program = 0;
    }

        if (m_ui32Vbo) 
    {
                glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_ui32Vbo);
                m_ui32Vbo = 0;
        }

        if (frameData) 
    {
                free(frameData);
        frameData = nil;
        }

    if (pTexData) 
    {
                free(pTexData);
        pTexData = nil;
        }

    // Tear down context.
    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];

    [context release];
    context = nil;

    [super dealloc];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ADLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self startAnimation];

}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self stopAnimation];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
        [super viewDidUnload];

    if (program)
    {
        glDeleteProgram(program);
        program = 0;
    }

    // Tear down context.
    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
        self.context = nil; 
}



- (void)startAnimation
{

    ADLog(@"startAnimation");

    if (displayLink)
    {
        [displayLink invalidate];
        displayLink = nil;
    }

    if (animating==FALSE && displayLink==nil)
    {
            ADLog(@"generating displayLink");
            displayLink = [NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink") displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(drawFrame)];
            [displayLink setFrameInterval:animationFrameInterval];
            [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            animating = TRUE;

    }

    ADLog(@"startAnimation end");

}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    ADLog(@"stopAnimation");

    if (displayLink)
    {

        [displayLink invalidate];
        displayLink = nil;

        animating   = FALSE;
    }


}


// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession 
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Create the session
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your 
    // processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the
    // chosen device.
        // Low   : 192 x 144
        // Medium: 480 x 320
        // High  : 1280 x 720
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice
                                                           defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
    input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    if (!input) 
    {
        // Handling the error appropriately.
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    // Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
    output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

    [session addOutput:output];

    // Configure your output.
    CaptureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("CaptureQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:CaptureQueue];
    dispatch_release(CaptureQueue);

    // Specify the pixel format
    output.videoSettings = 
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] 
                                                                forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

        output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = NO;

    //  If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 15 fps, set 
    //  minFrameDuration.
    //  [output setVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 20)];

    // Start the session running to start the flow of data

    [session startRunning];

}



@end
```

Any suggestions to track this crash  ?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up the view too soon. Most of the above code should be in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear:`, not `init`.

See also ["wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003/1384584#1384584)

Comment: moving the most of the init code to viewDidLoad remove the wait_fences log but is not resolving the crash . I got (randomly) a crash on memmove$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 196 OR in the capture queue thread

Comment: I notice that you're not using accessors. The most common cause of crashes is to directly access your ivars. Switch to accessors. Also, why are you using `NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink")`? Most suspicious your call to `dispatch_release(CaptureQueue);` Putting aside the incorrect naming (variables should be camel case with no leading cap), you seem to be releasing your own ivar?

Comment: i changed to  displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self
                                                  selector:@selector(drawFrame)]; (it was a copy/paste from a project on github) + moved dispatch_release to dealloc >> same problem

Comment: But you didn't switch to accessors. You're not retaining displayLink. You're going to have problems if setupCaptureSession can be called more than once. Again, accessors would protect against that. Also, you'll want to post the actual stack trace rather than the assembler.

Comment: And `drawFrame` is private. Why do you believe it's ok to make that call, and that you can safely do it at this point?

Comment: I m not understanding in which cases setupCaptureSession can be called more than once. the class is derived from UIViewController and there is as far as I know I dont call it twice. here is the stack trace screenshot : http://accessdev.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/stacktrace_so.png. for the accessors I dont know what you mean. setting up a property for displayLink instead of iVar dont solve the problem. maybe I made something wrong, but really dont know why .. and it s the first time I m facing this problem.