# UIWebOverflowScrollView Exception in Phonegap Application

Tags: objective-c, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing Phonegap app for iPad using jQuery mobile. My App works fine. But sometime it gives this exception.

"-[UIWebOverflowScrollView _viewDelegate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8f2cb70"

Anyone know what is the reason for that?

Thank you

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem over here. Could you please tell me if you have found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems u r releasing something prematurely, u may use Allocations Tool with Zombie enabled to find out what is that object..
Are u on iOS >= 5.0?

Comment: **I** enabled zombie.How to find out that object.? IOS 5.1 and Xcode 4.3.2

Comment: Just run the App in the simulator and lead to the crash, with a Zombie enabled u- will shall get a Stack trace on the console which shall help u trace the object.

Comment: I run the app in iPad and i got that error '[UIWebOverflowScrollView _viewDelegate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8f2cb70_ '. I think _viewDelegate is the object.

Comment: Thats a function(message sent) in the object which is prematurely released.. try using Tools->Allocations->Check NSZombie, C++ obj-> Run

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this ? I cnt find Tools. Where is it?

Comment: @Ishank- Do you know what is the meaning of this error "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003

Comment: @Ishank: he is using PhoneGap, so he is not allocating or releasing any objects. This is a wrong answer for his problem.