# PhoneGap + iOS exception: [UIWebOverflowScrollView _viewDelegate] message sent to deallocated instance 0x21e330

Tags: iphone, cordova, uiwebview, crash, barcode-scanner

after using my App created with PhoneGap + iOS for some time, the app crashes with following error message:

```
[UIWebOverflowScrollView _viewDelegate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x21e330
```

I have no idea why this problem is happening. I can not reproduce the error, it happens just suddenly. I am aware that this problem is related to any kind of object that has been released, but as I am using PhoneGap (+ QrCode Plugin) I am sure that this problem is related to Phonegap or to the BarcodeScanner plugin. Could someone give me any insights on how to solve this problem? I have updated to the new PhoneGap version 1.9.0.

Related question: [UIWebOverflowScrollView Exception in Phonegap Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378946/uiweboverflowscrollview-exception-in-phonegap-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" in your CSS?

We had the same problem with our phonegap-app, it sometimes crashed with the same error message (and sometimes only locked up the upper screen), and it got fixed by removing that said bit of CSS.

If you are using "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch", perhaps test if you can get your app to crash without it?

See [apache.org](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-593) for more info on the said bug and possible solutions.

We solved the situation by using [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) instead of the CSS.

Sorry for the late answer, we just got our problem fixed :P.