# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 - during application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am getting the "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003" during the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

I have subclassed UIWindow and overridden the drawRect method which is what is causing the error.  However, I have no idea what the error is trying to tell me, why it is occurring and how to fix it.

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {

        window_ = [[OoviumWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];
        controller_ = [[AetherController alloc] init];  
        [window_ setRootViewController:controller_];

        return YES;
    }



    @implementation OoviumWindow

    - (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect {
        if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect]) {
            _image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait.png"] retain];
        }
        return self;
    }
    // UIWindow ======================================================================================
    - (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        [_image drawInRect:_rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:.05];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is effectively a duplicate of ["wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003)

Your symptoms are slightly different in that you are using `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but the end result is that you are triggering rendering operations too early in the app lifecycle.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those solutions are relevant.  And given my code, it isn't clear that I'm triggering any rendering operations.  Obviously, something is causing the UIWindow to render, but I'm not sure what I can do about it, since it's not being triggered by my code.

Comment: @aepryus: `makeKeyAndVisible` will cause your window to be drawn -- how else would it become visible?

Comment: Fair enough..  But isn't it required that that method be called during application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ?