# warning : wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uialertview

I am getting this warning sometimes " wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003  ", do not know why this is coming,

I do not have viewdidiappear method in my code, i have a UIAlert in my view, the code is

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi %@,",[user objectAtIndex:0] ] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: I have searched but could not figure out thing, so i have put a Question here...do not give negative rating

Comment: Please take a look at this SO answer


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003

Comment: @ shabzco : nowhere in my code i am using a textfield, so what to do, could u help me out

Answer (score 0):

this is due to UI actions on a view controller on which you are not currently,i.e. the screen of which you are accessing UI, not visible currently.

Comment: Okay, So what solution can i give it, for not making the warning.

Comment: in init method, i have a method named next(), in that method i have the alert.

Comment: look, your init is invoked when you are going to make an object of that class not when you are on screen, which class u are using, is that uiviewcontroller subclass?

Comment: yeah and cleared it Thank u @The Saad, i am caling it from the previous class

Answer (score 0):

if you read my answer in the comment you would understand, but what you need to do is add the above code in the `-viewDidAppear` method and make sure you add `[super viewDidAppear:YES];` and if you want to keep it in your init method you'll have to add a delay like so
`[self performSelector:@selector(next) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];`

Comment: Could u tell me why is that happening and without delay can't we do that, i mean do we have any other method.

Comment: it happens because you are creating your AlertView before its parent/super view. I have given you an answer, I don't know what else you want. put it in your -viewDidAppear method and it will work.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that the same viewcontroller has lots of uiviews in it so, i guess the alert would create a problem if i keep in viewdidappear.