# UIAlertView, NSURLConnection and wait_fences

Tags: ios, alertview, wait-fences

I'm trying to display a `UIAlertView` with `UIActivityIndicator` after a user presses "log in" in a modal view controller. To log in, the credentials are sent to a server using `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` from the `NSURLConnection` class. My implementation is as follows:

```
UIAlertView * spinner = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connecting to server..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[spinner show];
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(spinner.bounds.size.width * 0.5f, spinner.bounds.size.height * 0.5f+5.0f);
[indicator startAnimating];
[spinner addSubview:indicator];
[indicator release];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * res, NSData * data, NSError * err) {
    [spinner dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [spinner release];
    ...
}
```

This seems to work fine if the server can't be reached or the server is slow, but if the server replies immediatly, the spinner doesn't seem to be dismissed until after 3-5 seconds with the console logging

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

I think this happens because I'm dismissing a modal view controller (the log in screen) while the `UIAlertView` is still showing but I'm not sure why this happens as it should normally be dismissed. Am I doing something wrong and what would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this log several times - it is always caused by an unexpected state in the internal animation framework or a collision between default view animations.

Possible reasons:

1. Starting animations from inside `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or similar method - before the view is actually displayed.
2. Showing/Hiding a `UIAlertView` when another `UIAlertView` animation is still running. This includes showing an alert from `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`.
3. Collision between modal view animation and alert animation.
4. Collision between `UINavigationController` push/pop animation and alert animation.

**Your case**: You are probably hiding your alert even before it has been fully displayed and you get a collision between the two animations. The showing animation takes usually about 0.4 seconds but your response can arrive much earlier - triggering the hiding animation.

Possible solution:

1. Trigger request when your animation ends (`didPresentAlertView`).
2. Measure the duration of your connection and if it`s shorter than 0.4 secs, delay the hiding animation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will look into the didPresentAlertView method and accept this answer if that seems to solve it.

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of my program I solved it in a different matter but the problem was indeed the one you described: I had to wait a little longer to call dismiss. I now use dispatch_after with a block that contains my old dismiss code and not only is my program more responsive but the UI wait_fences error is gone too! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do animations if the View Controller on which that animation is taking place did not appear. So no animations in viewDidLoad. Try in viewDidAppear. That's safer. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1384584/624091).

Hope this helps.

Cheers!