# iPhone zXing QR Scanner - didscanresult function never fires

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, qr-code, zxing

I have loaded the zXing project into my own project.
It loads fine, the zXing scanner pops up after a button call.

I can dismiss the view controller on thezxingControllerDidCancel but when I scan a QR code, no codes are ever recognised and therefore the didScanResult function never fires.

Does anyone have any idea about this one?

The didScanResult function is below.

```
-(void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController *)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result{
resultLabel.text = result;
NSLog(@"did scan!!!");
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

}

Note: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but when the scanner comes up, I get this logged by the app: "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"

Comment: Could you post how you create and show the ZXingWidgetController?

Comment: Basically I ran through this tutorial on adding it to my project (http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/)

So I imported them into my viewcontrollers .h file

Used the 'didScanResult' and 'zxingControllerDidCancel' functions of the ZXingDelegate. 
zxingControllerDidCancel works perfectly as previously stated. 

Does this help?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003) to solve the 10004003 Error.

Comment: That tutorial does not mention that you must add a QRCodeReader to the set of readers of your ZXingWidgetController.

Comment: @ilmiacs Thanks for that.  But what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial does not mention that you must add a `QRCodeReader` to the set of readers of your `ZXingWidgetController`.

`ZXingWidgetController` has a property called `readers`, which is an `NSSet` containing the instances of the readers (e.g. an instance of `QRCodeReader`). Roughly, the readers' task is to analyze the images your camera takes and to extract the encoded information. Your `ZXingWidgetController` has to know about the readers it should utilize, otherwise it has no chance to do anything meaningful. So you have to set the `readers` property before you present the ZXingWidget.

The ZXing project has a sample app which demonstrates this. If you use ARC, then

```
ZXingWidgetController *widController = [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];
QRCodeReader* qRCodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];
NSSet *readers = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:qRCodeReader,nil];
widController.readers = readers;
[self presentModalViewController:widController animated:YES];
```

should do.

Comment: You sure are a champion! Thank you very much for your help - It's working perfectly now :)