# Animation in for loop compounds everytime view appears

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to get a fresh set of random animations each time the view loads, but instead I am getting the animations multiplying and leading to the inevitable application meltdown! Any help on how to get a fresh start each time the view appears

```
- (void)startAnimation
   {
int n;

for (n=0; n<150; n++){

    UIBezierPath *bubblePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bubblePath moveToPoint:P(arc4random()%768, arc4random()%1024)];
    [bubblePath addCurveToPoint:P(arc4random()%768, arc4random()%1024)
                  controlPoint1:P(arc4random()%768, arc4random()%1024)
                  controlPoint2:P(arc4random()%768, arc4random()%1024)];


    CALayer *bubble = [CALayer layer];
    bubble.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10.0, 10.0);
    bubble.position = CGPointMake(arc4random()%768, arc4random()%1024);
    bubble.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"Bubble.png"].CGImage);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:bubble];



    CAKeyframeAnimation *bubbleAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    bubbleAnim.path = bubblePath.CGPath;
    bubbleAnim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
    bubbleAnim.duration = 100;
    bubbleAnim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [bubble addAnimation:bubbleAnim forKey:@"bubble"];

}

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<8; i++){

        UIBezierPath *tinyPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [tinyPath moveToPoint:P(arc4random()%400+840, arc4random()%75+125)];
        [tinyPath addCurveToPoint:P(-400, arc4random()%75+150)
                    controlPoint1:P(arc4random()%450, arc4random()%200+250)
                    controlPoint2:P(arc4random()%300, arc4random()%200+150)];


        CALayer *tinyFish = [CALayer layer];
        tinyFish.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150.0, 150.0);
        tinyFish.position = CGPointMake(868, 800);
        tinyFish.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"Fish3.png"].CGImage);
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:tinyFish];

        CAKeyframeAnimation *tinyAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        tinyAnim.path = tinyPath.CGPath;
        tinyAnim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
        tinyAnim.duration = 15;
        tinyAnim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
        [tinyFish addAnimation:tinyAnim forKey:@"fish"];

    }
```

}

Comment: Well , to do it every time the view appears , you have to call this method in `viewDidAppear` of course. Animations before `viewDidAppear` like for example in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` are not recommended. This is why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1384584/624091 . Also , I'm not sure about the behavior that you want here, but the thing is that by calling this in `viewDidAppear` it will add all those layers each time they appear. So you should remove them from the `superlayer` after the animation is done. Not sure about the HUGE_VAL either. What is the wanted behavior?

Comment: I do call [self startAnimation]; in viewDidAppear, and the effect is random floating bubbles and fish swimming on the screen. The problem is that the layers never get removed and every time the viewAppears the animation multiplies!

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^
{
     //do your animations here
}completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    //remove all layers here. Eventually add here another animation where you fade out all layers and in that animation's completion block remove them from the view
}];
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!