# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 dismiss AlertView

Tags: ios, runtime-error, alertview

I have a alertView that opens perfectly, but in the moment of dismiss crashes and gives this error and the app crashes

**wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)w shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
 {
   //......
   UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event"
                                                      message:@""
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
    [message release];

   //.....
 }
```

Comment: Are you using blocks?

Comment: Are you using in background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please let me know where you are using this alertview code? it means in which method and in which class?

Also, try to look at this link : ["wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003)

And let me know if you need any other help.